# NETXEN CX4 10G NIC Drivers for Windows 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, 10gbethernet

I am searching for a Network Card Driver, the nic is "NetXen 10Gb (CX4) Ethernet Protocol Offload Adapter"

I am using this adapter on a Windows 2008R2 Box - Once I installed windows - it had already installed the NIC for me so I was happy :-), Assigned it a IP (Static) and after a few hours the server itself had freezing issues and had to be hard-booted as it was completely non-responsive (we left the server for an hour) but it still was UN-responsive.

all of my googling had led me to QLogic, they have the drivers but they are for Windows 2003, I read on there website that they have now given these nics to HP or something like that.

So, was wondering and will be grateful if someone over here could point me to the right direction or help me troubleshoot this, the server in question is a Dl380G7 and we want to use this card in there or if not we can use it in a Dell R710.

If someone from HP or a contributor can either point me to the right drivers for this nic or to change / disable some setting which will overcome the freezing issue - that would be highly appreciated.

I read on a forum to disable TSO (TCP Segmentation offload) but that is not an option when I right click on the already installed nic in Windows 2008R2 - it isn't available.

Any help - will be grateful

Thanks !!

Comment: Call your HP reseller

Comment: thank you so much :-) I will do that but I am curious as to why the driver is installed and nic is available under 2008R2 - if the driver was not there it would have had an exclamation mark on it, do u think there may be a setting on the nic's advanced properties ?

Answer (score 0):

As you note, Qlogic bought this and they then discontinued driver development.  There are a number of posts looking for a 2008 driver but all replies indicate Server 2003 only.

The lack of the exclamation mark would indicate it is installed OK.  However, there may be tuning that can be done.  One thing to check.  Can you set speed and duplex manually on the card and the connected switch?  If so, try setting teh card to say 1000 Full and the switch same and see what happens.  I have seen settings of Auto/Auto create issues.  You can try various setting to see if changing helps but always match card and switch for speed and duplex.

Comment: Hi DaveM, Thank you for your input, can you provide some tips / reasons as to why this may be freezing the server ? When I first installed it, configured it with a static IP on SRV 2008R2, did a few data transfers - it was fine - but when users start accessing it, then it started freezing the server, when we reverted back to the gig nics all was fine. Do you think there may be a setting on this nic which may tune it ? I think if a device is not showing an exclamation mark under device manager - it is installed fine ? or am I wrong - Will look forward to your thoughts-Thanks